# React js with Visual Studio - cant find components

Tags: c#, reactjs, visual-studio

I'm trying to make the simplest react file with Visual Studio using C#. I have a component I'm trying to stick into the home page that was auto generated.

I keep getting the error that the component is not found. I have def used the correct route. It's in the same folder as `Home.js`.

Can anyone think of a line I am missing or a reason why exactly this will not work?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CanvasWithSquare from './CanvasWithSquare'; // Correct the path based on your project structure
export class Home extends Component {
    static displayName = Home.name;

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <CanvasWithSquare />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const CanvasWithSquare = () => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Draw a square
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue'; // Fill color of the square
        ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100); // Draw a square at (50, 50) with size 100x100
    }, []);

    return <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={400} height={400} />;
};

export default CanvasWithSquare;
```

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './CanvasWithSquare' in 'C:\Users\tbrockington\source\repos\RankingApp\RankingApp\ClientApp\src\components'
>
> ERROR in ./src/components/Home.js 5:0-50
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './CanvasWithSquare' in 'C:\Users\tbrockington\source\repos\RankingApp\RankingApp\ClientApp\src\components'
>
> webpack compiled with 1 error

I tried changing the names, namespaces, location, route address

Comment: Are your `Home` and `CanvasWithSquare` components both in the same file? If so then you don't need to `import CanvasWithSquare`. If they're in different files then please edit your question to clearly indicate which code is in what file.